# how does `shopt -s lastpipe` affect bash script behavior?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to make [ffcast](https://github.com/lolilolicon/FFcast) screen casting tool bash 4.1 backwards compatible.

and in this [ffcast.bash](https://github.com/lolilolicon/FFcast/blob/master/src/ffcast.bash#L26) script, there is oneline

```
shopt -s extglob lastpipe
```

lastpipe option is only available after bash 4.3, what can I do to emulate its effect?

Answer (score 10):

`lastpipe` (introduced in bash 4.2, by the way) can only be simulated by not using a pipe. You need to explicitly run the last command of the pipe line in the current shell, and redirect its input from either a process substitution

```
# foo | bar | baz becomes ...
baz < <(foo | bar)
```

or a named pipe (which is POSIX-compliant as well)

```
# foo | bar | baz becomes ...
mkfifo baz_input
foo | bar > baz_input &
baz < baz_input
```

Comment: Those aren't equivalent. This code shows a difference. `i=0; f() { echo "$1: $((i++))"; }; shopt -u lastpipe; true | f piped; true | f piped; shopt -s lastpipe; true | f lastpiped; true | f lastpiped; f redirected < <(true); f redirected < <(true)` .  Only the redirected input correctly saves the incremented counter, regardless of `lastpipe` status.

Comment: That's because you are in an interactive shell with job control active; job control needs to be deactivated (for reasons I've never quite understood) for `lastpipe` to take effect. If you put that code in a script, you'll see `lastpiped` version does increment `i` across calls. (You can also use `set +m` to disable job control in an interactive shell.)

Comment: Thanks! It works in a script. Mind adding the job control and script vs interactive bit to your answer?

Answer (score 9):

Usual behavior without `lastpipe` and with job control enabled is to run each element of the pipeline in a sub-shell.

```
echo asd | var=$(cat) ; echo $var
```

`var` contains nothing, but user may expect that `var` will contain `asd`. That is because last pipeline element sets `var` in a sub-shell which has no access to current shell's environment.

From `man bash`:

> Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell).  See COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT for a description of a subshell environment.  If the lastpipe option  is  enabled  using
>          the shopt builtin (see the description of shopt below), the last element of a pipeline **may be** run by the shell process.

I don't know what is **may be**... 
Here is better description:

> **`lastpipe`**
>                         If set, and job control is not active, the shell runs the last command of a pipeline not executed in the background in the current shell environment.

So

```
set +m  # To disable job control
shopt -s lastpipe
echo asd | var=$(cat)
echo $var
```

and now `var` contains `asd`.

Thanks @chepner.

---

Earlier I used to write like:

```
{ while read;do var="$REPLY";done; } < <(command | filter)
```

in cases when

```
var=$(command | filter)
```

is not suitable.