# How to get information from a while loop after a pipe in bash

Tags: bash, while-loop, pipe

From this trivial example:

```
$ x="ls output: "
$ ls | while read line; do x="$x $line"; echo $x; done
ls output: a
ls output: a b
ls output: a b c
ls output: a b c d
$ echo $x
ls output:
```

it seems the pipe character starts a new shell, which does get a copy of the variable `x`, but at the end of the pipe, the value of `x` inside that value is not copied back to the outer shell.

Is there any way I can get it out?

Note: I know there are much better / simpler ways to get this particular thing done, but this is just a simplified example.  My question is how to get information out of a while loop after a pipe.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: `x="ls output: $(echo *)"` or better: `printf -v x '%q ' *; x="ls output: $x"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When job control is disabled and the `lastpipe` option is enabled, the last component of a pipeline is run in the current execution environment. See

```
$ x=foo
$ set +m # disables job control
$ shopt -s lastpipe
$ echo | x=bar
$ echo $x
bar
```

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately `lastpipe` was apparently added in bash 4.2 and I'm running 4.1.2.  For older versions, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36340599/how-does-shopt-s-lastpipe-affect-bash-script-behavior).