# How to have bash inherit failures from stdin subshells

Tags: bash, exception

Given the following contrived code:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -Eeuo pipefail
shopt -s inherit_errexit

echo 'before'

mapfile -t tuples < <(exit 1)
# ^ what option do I need to enable so the error exit code from this is not ignored

echo 'after'
```

Which produces:

```
before
after
```

Is there a set or shopt option that can be turned on such that `<(exit 1)` will cause the caller to inherit the failure, and thus preventing `after` from being executed? Such as what `inherit_errexit` and `pipefail` do in other contexts.

Comment: The problem is that the shell doesn't wait for a process run with process substitution to exit before executing the next command. So nothing that depends on its exit status can be used.

Comment: This allows you to run programs that never exit in a process substitution, e.g. `head -10 < <(tail -f filename)`

Comment: @Barmar bummer, yeah seems (1) `<(...)` is shorthand for create a file which output is done via `...`, with the implementation discarding any errors https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution (2) that `mapfile` because of this also only emits errors with mapfile https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins

Comment: @Barmar is there an alternative syntax then that is recommended for when I do want to respect the error code? Or is the only option check if the mapfile variable is empty after the fact?

Comment: For those wondering, `mapfile -t tuples <<< "$(exit 1)"` also produces the same ignored behaviour.

Comment: You can use a pipe and bash's `$PIPESTATUS` array. But that won't work with `mapfile`, because it would be executed in a subshell, so the variable assignment wouldn't persist.

Comment: Guess the only option is`f="$(mktemp)"; exit 1 > "$f"; mapfile -t tuples < "$f"` then, which does catch the failure

Answer (score 2):

In `bash` 4.4 or later, process substitutions will set `$!`, which means you can wait on that process to get its exit status.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -Eeuo pipefail
shopt -s inherit_errexit

echo 'before'

mapfile -t tuples < <(exit 1)
wait $!

echo 'after'
```

`mapfile` itself (in general) won't have a non-zero status, because it's perfectly happy read what, if anything, the process substitution produces.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a variable with the output of the command. The variable assignment propagates errors from the command substitution.

```
t=$(exit 1)
echo 'after'
mapfile -t tuples <<<"$t"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have Bash 4.2 or later, since you are already setting `errexit` and `pipefail`, you can avoid the problem by using:

```
...
shopt -s lastpipe
exit 1 | mapfile -t tuples
```

`shopt -s lastpipe` causes the last command in a pipeline to be run in the current shell.  See [how does `shopt -s lastpipe` affect bash script behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36340599/4154375).  In this case it means that a `tuples` value read by `mapfile` can be accessed later in the code.